# data representation with nominal, ordinal and continuous variables

Tags: regression, independence

Suppose I have data of this format:

customer, country, location, unit price, traffic, etc. (more nominal/ordinal variables)

I want to know how country affects unit price, how do I go about doing this using

a. some measures of dependence
b. regression models

I'm totally confused as to how i could represent this data for fitting a model since country is nominal and there is a set of prices (with some frequencies) for every country.

Thank you.

Comment: The hard part of this question concerns how to cope with a *discrete* set of values of your dependent variable, the unit prices. Could you please then tell us a little more about them? Why are these prices limited to just a few values?  How many distinct values are there?

Comment: @whuber extremely sorry, I realised an edit: unit prices are continuous. Should I record some statistics measuring bivariate dependence on nominal variables {One way ANOVA, mutual information, Kruskal Wallis etc.} ? Would that make sense as an apriori to regression analysis?

Answer (score 1):

for the use of nominal data, please look up dummy variables for regression models. if you have N countries, introduce N-1 new variables. each country is represented by a dummy variable apart from 1 (because of linear dependency). If a row (sample) contains a country, the corresponding dummy variable will be 1, all the other 0. This also allows you to see which countries are relevant for your model. I hope this will help your on your way looking more into regression.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a textbook application for multilevel models/hierarchical models/mixed models. If you have many countries, then if think about it, you do *not* want to include to dozens to hundreds of indicator/dummy variables for each country. If `location` is similarly defined you may run to many thousands of indicators variables presenting you with difficult to organize results, and a great loss of statistical power as your degrees of freedom drop with each additional variable. If each `country` has characteristics that may affect its effect on price, then you can *really* see the too many variables issue blowing up.

With a multilevel modeling approach you might instead treat each country as contributing its own unique variance to the constant/intercept term in your model, and the include country-level variables as predictors without having to interact them across dozens, hundreds or thousands of indicators variables.

For a good introductory read to orient you to these kinds of models, see Duncan, C., Jones, K., and Moon, G. (1998). [Context, composition and heterogeneity: Using multilevel models in health research](http://www.med.upenn.edu/beat/docs/Duncan1998.pdf). *Social Science & Medicine*, 46(1):97–117.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this seems like THE approach. What I was also thinking was to use some sort of tree based segmentation (CART etc.) on nominal variables and then performing a regression analysis on each segment. What do you think?